# How to display the value of a field only when the Save button is pressed in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a computed field that generates a sequence when a product selects . But I don't want the sequence to be generated at the time that the product to Form view is added. What I want is that only the value is added to the sequence when the Save button is pressed the header .

Is it possible to do that?

Is there any way to validate a field if a button is pressed or not?

The following image shows that when I add an element to the form , the sequence is created. But I want the sequence is created only when the save button is pressed.

Image: http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/image1d001867bb69d2ffa90c65209e81976cc.php

And this is the field and function. But only the sequence is generated when the save button is pressed:

```
  niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", readonly=True, store=True)

    @api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
    def _niu_validation(self):
        for recordset in self:
            if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
                    rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

I hope you understand what I really mean.

Thanks for all.

Comment: As I understood, you want to save `niu` values when user press **Save** button on main form. But what should see users in column `NIU` when they added some lines?

Comment: You have to update sequence only when the Save button is pressed.because as you wrote the sequence is updated each time niu field is computed.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something better suited to jquery and very simple. First, either within the css or on the element itself set display=none. Then within a script add this:

```
$('#save_button).click(function(this){
    $(this).preventdefault();
    $('#thing_youre_hiding').toggle();
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: Your answer with mistake. `$('#save_button)` -> `$('#save_button')`. Do you know something about Odoo? Odoo use backbone API's, qWeb, widgets etc. I think write scripts on jQuery for openrERP applications it is not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think i'am late but if you don't want to show any field in view when the user is still editing give it `class="oe_readonly"`.